# $n$th power sum of two terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could I ask if anyone has come across a non-recursive formula that gives the $n$th power sum of two variables in terms of their sum ($s$) and product ($p$). For example:

Given $a+b=-1$ and $a^2+b^2=-2$, which leads to $s=-1$ & $p=\frac{3}{2}$

Show that:

$$a^{11}+b^{11}=s^{11}-11s^9p+44s^7p^2-77s^5p^3+55s^3p^4-11sp^5$$

Using sequential method, I was able to verify that the above LHS is identical to RHS. However, I could not find out how the RHS is generated.


This is providing a faster approach to the desired $n$th power sum and it would be particularly useful for higher values of $n$.

Comment: What does $(a+b)^{11}$ do for you?

Comment: IMHO $a^2+b^2=-2$ does _not_ lead anywhere.

Comment: ...unless you intend to explore the space of complex numbers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
a^n  + b^n  = s(a^{n - 1}  + b^{n - 1} ) - p(a^{n - 2}  + b^{n - 2} )
$$
and $a^0+b^0=2$, $a+b=s$. Comparing this with the recurrence $(\text{a}1)$ for the [Lucas polynomials](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lucas_polynomials) $V_n(x)$, we find that
$$
a^n  + b^n  = ({\rm i}\sqrt p )^n V_n \!\left( {\frac{s}{{{\rm i}\sqrt p }}} \right)
$$
with $\mathrm{i}^2=-1$. By the explicit formula $(\text{a}8)$ for these polynomials, it follows that
$$
a^n  + b^n  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor } {( - 1)^j \frac{n}{{n - j}}\binom{n - j}{j}s^{n - 2j} p^j } .
$$
Alternatively, observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(a^n  + b^n )z^n }  &= \frac{1}{{1 - az}} + \frac{1}{{1 - bz}} = \frac{{2 - sz}}{{pz^2  - sz + 1}} \\ & = \cfrac{1}{{1 - \cfrac{{s + \sqrt {s^2  - 4p} }}{2}z}} + \cfrac{1}{{1 - \cfrac{{s - \sqrt {s^2  - 4p} }}{2}z}},
\end{align*}
which leads to
\begin{align*}
a^n  + b^n  & = \left( {\frac{{s + \sqrt {s^2  - 4p} }}{2}} \right)^n  + \left( {\frac{{s - \sqrt {s^2  - 4p} }}{2}} \right)^n \\ & = \frac{1}{{2^{n - 1} }}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor } {\binom{n}{2j}s^{n - 2j}(s^2  - 4p)^j  } .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you Gary. I have tried the formula and it works beautifully. It is wonderful when "form" is revealed rather than just solving a problem.

Comment: HI, sorry I'm new here. How can I accept and vote?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers